# Aggregate objects by summing a filed using a limit value with Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

aGiven a list of the following:

```
public interface Node{
    int getCount();
    String getName();
}
```

and a limit:
`int limit = 10`

How can one collect/group all nodes where `node1.getCount() + node2.getCount() <= limit`

For example, if the constructor first parameter is 'count' and the second is 'name':

```
   var nodes = Arrays.asList(
      new Node(5, "node1"), 
      new Node(5, "node2"), 
      new Node(5, "node3"),
      new Node(20, "node4")
```

will result in some data structure that groups node1 and node2 together and node3 as another entry.

If using a list of lists the expected result should be:

```
[[node1, node2], [node3], [node4]]
```

Comment: 20 -> [node4] you mean 10 -> [node4] ?

Comment: Why isn't node2 and node3 part of key 10?

Comment: yep it could be also Node 1 with Node 3

Comment: 10 -> [node1, node2], This would never work because you would have a Map with multiple same keys

Comment: Unless you have a list of list has the value

Comment: The explanation has been changes due to the helpful comments

Comment: Do not use streams for this. They are unsuited for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure using streams for this is the most optimal solution. You could try this:

```
private List<Pair> calcPairs(Node[] nodes, int limit) {
    // Sort node by count value
    Arrays.sort(nodes, Comparator.comparingInt(Node::getCount));

    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

    // The index that points to the largest node that could possibly match with the
    // remaining nodes to find matches for
    int possibleMatchMaxIndex = nodes.length - 1;

    // Go over all nodes in ascending order
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        // Go over all nodes in reverse order starting from the largest possible candidate
        // and ending with the node before the one we're finding pairs for
        for (int j = possibleMatchMaxIndex; j > i; j--) {
            if (nodes[i].getCount() + nodes[j].getCount() <= limit) {
                pairs.add(new Pair(nodes[i], nodes[j]));
            } else {
                // Decrease the index of the largest possible candidate, because if nodes[i]
                // combined with nodes[j] does not fit within the limit, we can be sure nodes[i + 1]
                // combined with nodes[j] doesn't fit within the limit either since we're going
                // trough them in ascending order.
                possibleMatchMaxIndex--;
            }
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

A possible solution using streams, but this also matches each element with itself and checks every possible combination, even if we know they can't possibly fit within the limit based on earlier mismatches:

```
private List<Pair> calcPairsStream(Node[] nodes, int i) {
    return Stream.of(nodes)
            .flatMap(node1 -> Stream.of(nodes)
                    .filter(node2 -> node1.getCount() + node2.getCount() <= i)
                    .map(node2 -> new Pair(node1, node2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```